# The background image don't appear

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

so in viewport I can see it but in render no, I checked everything, ask chat gpt, etc.
[image]

Comment: Transparent is on

Comment: Background images are not supposed to be rendered. Please tell that to chat gpt for the next time.

Comment: i see a tutorial  that does it...

Answer (score 0):

Background images do not appear in renders by definition; they only exist in the viewport since they are treated as empties. Thus, Background images are only useful as references.

It seems you are working on a comp shot, so I would recommend simply using the compositor in this case. In the Properties tab under Render Properties, set the film type to Transparent. This way your rendered image will have an automatic alpha channel. That way, you can layer it over your background image in the compositor or in an external program later.

There is another method that I would **not** recommend for this project, but that comes closer to what you were originally trying to do (and is very useful in other scenarios), so I will add it here:

To add an image into your scene, you can add the image as a plane. To do this, enable the "Import images as planes" add-on in the add-on settings (this add-on comes with Blender). This gives you the option to import images into the scene as planes with an image texture. You can then move this image behind the other objects.

Note that this means your image will be affected by lights, shadows and the settings of the material of the plane, so to retain the original colour, you will have to feed the image directly into the material output without shader nodes and set your colour space to standard instead of filmic. The plane will also not follow the camera unless you add a tracking constraint.

Comment: i did what you said about the transparent, and nothing, I saw tutorials about rendering background images but it doesnt work anymore

Comment: @Pep Rendering the film as transparent will NOT render the background image. The background image cannot be rendered. However, if you enable transparency, you can layer the render result over the image in another program or in the compositor.